# Statistical analyses for framing effect study

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, statistics, gender

I am running a study to determine if women are more influenced than menby the framing effect.

I designed a survey with three overall questions, each with a "positive frame" and a "negative frame". Each participant would be randomly chosen to answer either the positive or negative frame, and each frame would have a 1-6 Likert scale where each participant rates whether or not they would choose one of two options presented in the questions' scenarios (i.e. rate 1 for definitely choosing drug A and rate 6 for definitely choosing drug B). I already compared the means of the positive frame and negative frame for each gender using a two-sample t-test (see table below), and I was wondering how I would go about analyzing whether or not women are more influenced by the framing effect.

I have a few questions:

1. Using this scale, can I assume that the scale is linear - i.e. is the change from 5 to 6 the same as from 1 to 2 or from 2 to 3?
2. Can I use t-tests and means to report and interpret the results of the experiment?
3. In comparing the male and female differences in the two frames (i.e comparing the statistical significance between 0.592 and 0.724), should I consider a difference in the absolute level (i.e. F-M, so 0.724-0.592 = 0.132) or a difference in magnitude (F/M = 0.724/0.592 = 1.223)? How would I run statistical tests to determine significance for either approach?
4. The original question - how I would go about analyzing whether or not females are more influenced by the framing effect?

[image: Array of results for 6 subjects]

[image: Example of one frame of one question]